# Twitter/PayPal Framework for PHP

Tags: php, twitter, paypal

Is there any framework that would allow me to integrate paypal with twitter, such as to send a tweet once payment for an item has been recieved. I'll be programming this with PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PayPal has an API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_overview) which may provide what you're looking for as far as learning about an event.

As for the Twitter aspect, the [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) shows several methods for posting messages on Twitter.

It's all a matter of gluing the two and possibly integrating it with your system.